# Remove a migration with an empty down method or alter stored procedure from another migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am working on a stored procedure that generates some tax data and stores that data into a separate table in the database. A while back I created an empty migration and added the following to the migration to add the stored procedure to the DB.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace Tax.Data.Migrations
{
    public partial class sp_Generate5498TaxData : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            var sp = @"USE [TAX_DB]
                GO
                SET ANSI_NULLS ON
                GO
                SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
                GO
                CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GenerateTaxData

                @Year int
                AS
                BEGIN
                   -- A bunch of SQL that is the stored procedure

                END
                GO";

            migrationBuilder.Sql(sp);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Without thinking about it I added the migration without putting anything in the down method. Now, I need to alter the stored procedure and I am not sure how to do it so as to not cause other issues. My initial though was to remove the migration and add a new one but since the down method is empty would this cause any issues? Can I just write the following into the down method of the existing migration?

```
public override void Down()
    {
        this.Sql("DROP PROCEDURE sp_GenerateTaxData");
    }
```

My other thought was to create a new migration and add in my SQL that instead says ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GenerateTaxData but again I am not sure what the side effects of this would be. I have looked around and cannot find information on how to best do this because of my mistake of not setting the down method initially. Any suggestions on how I can remote the existing migration or add a new one that will update the SP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a migration without a down method is not necessarily an error. It just means that if you revert the migration, what was done in the `Up` method won't be undone in the database when reverting it. In this case, removing the migration from the database *won't actually drop the stored procedure from the database*, since you haven't instructed it in your `Down` method.

Therefore, you could just write the code for the `Down` method now, instructing EF Core to generate the script to remove your stored procedure. Then, when un-applying the migration EF will remove the stored procedure from the DB. It shouldn't matter that you write the Down code later on.

What you could also do is to remove the migration files and then manually drop the stored procedure from all involved databases (different environments and all local machines of the members of your team, which is not practical... that's what migrations more or less come to solve). However, if migration has been only applied in your local db and maybe one staging environment, you could do it manually without much hassle.

Finally, you could also just add a new migration where in the Up() method and alter the procedure, as you suggested.

IMO, you don't need to worry that much. The only problem (in this scenario) of not having the Down() method  is that you won't get the script to revert what was done in the Up() method automatically by EF (in this case, drop the stored procedure). It can be more problematic if the migration was changing the schema and there were also other migrations that had been applied afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for this answer this definitely clear up what is happening behind the scenes. Does this mean that since this migration s solely for a stored procedure and does not have any dependencies that I could just update the ```Up``` method of the existing migration with the ```ALTER PROCEDURE``` SQL?

Comment: @reusablePants I don't think that's actually an option. Think that if you change it to be ALTER PROCEDURE in the Up method, that implies that the DB must have already a Procedure created with such a name. Then consider what would happen if a new developer joins your team and wants to initialize the DB: it will start applying migration by migration and when finding the ALTER PROCEDURE one will fail because the recently created DB doesn't have it yet

Comment: @reusablePants If you, however, add a new migration where in the UP method you write the ALTER, that's guaranteed to work because when applying that migration, the previous one with the CREATE would have already been applied.

Comment: Okay, so not to beat a dead horse but just for clarity. Adding CREATE OR ALTER then could work?

Comment: @reusablePants that can actually work :) just remember that for the new code in the Up method of the existing migration to be applied when running update-database, you will need to first remove the migration name from the EFMigrationHistory table of your db (either manually, or by reverting the migration using update-database <name-of-the-previuos-migration). After that, you need to do update-database again to apply the migration with the changes in the code

Comment: @reusablePants also, before doing this, please make sure that you don't have any other migration after the one we are talking about. If you do, for unapplying and applying your migration again (with the updated script) you have to remove and re-apply all posterior migrations as well, which can result in data loss. If you do have migrations after the one that's creating the SP, I would just add a new migration at the end

Comment: Awesome! I am going to just do as you previously suggested in adding a new migration with the ALTER PROCEDURE command. I was just curious how it would work to just update the existing migration. It sounds like it is safer to just add a new one though.